# Eclipse for PHP error Java wa started but returned error code 13

Tags: java, php, eclipse

I am an absolute beginner to Eclipse and PHP or Java. I am trying to learn PHP  .So I installed ECLIPSE for PHP .But I am getting an error ( pasted below)

[image]

I also found this error from the log file in my eclipse  configuration folder eclipse-php-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\configuration

```
 !SESSION 2014-12-08 20:03:14.382 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.8.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-12-08 20:03:15.416
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

When I checked my JAVA version ,its showing

> ## java -version
>
> java version "1.8.0_25"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

The error message  shows required Java version as 1.7 . I searched for Java version 1.7 ,but I could not locate one.

Please help me resolve this error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM` is clear, you are running 64-bit SWT (Eclipse) in a 32-bit JVM (Java Virtual Machine) you have to download the 32-bit version of [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR1/eclipse-php-luna-SR1-win32.zip).

Or

If you have a 64-bit JVM installed change `eclipse.ini` file to point to the correct vm. Check this [link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example) for how to change.